# How to get the current logged user in unit test with Symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, unit-testing

I have this unit test :

```
class ProjectControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{

    private $client = null;
    private $projectName = null;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
     */
    private $em;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $kernel = static::createKernel();
        $kernel->boot();
        $this->client = $this->createAuthorizeClient($kernel);
        $this->em = $kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
    }

    public function testProjectNameEdition()
    {
        $project = new Project();
        $project
            ->setName(uniqid())
            ->setComment('test')
        ;
        $this->em->persist($project);
        $this->em->flush();

        $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/project/' . $project->getId() . '/edit');
        $form = $crawler->selectButton('codex_gui_project_submit')->form();
        $form['codex_gui_project[name]'] = $this->projectName . '1';
        $this->client->submit($form);

        $editProject = $this->em->getRepository('DatawordsCodexGuiBundle:Project')->findOneByName($oldProjectName . '1');
        $this->assertEquals($this->projectName . '1', $editProject->getName());
    }

    public function createAuthorizeClient($kernel)
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $container = $kernel->getContainer();
        $session = $container->get('session');
        $user = $kernel
            ->getContainer()->get('doctrine')
            ->getRepository('DatawordsCodexCoreBundle:User')
            ->findOneByUsername('Nico')
        ;
        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $user->getUserName(), 'main', $user->getRoles());

        $session->set('_security_main', serialize($token));
        $session->save();
        $client->getCookieJar()->set(new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId()));

        return $client;
    }

}
```

Then when the new entity is persisted, the current user is getting in the **ProjectListenner** :

```
class ProjectListener
{

    protected $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    /**
     * Prepersist a creation of project
     *
     * @param \Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs $args
     */
    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        if ($entity instanceof Project) {
            // Save the user and the created date
            $usr = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
            $entity->setCreated(new \DateTime());
            $entity->setCreator($usr);
    }
}
```

So this **error** happened when I run the test :

> **...PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function getUser() on a non-object in
>   /var/www/codex_gui/vendor/acme/foo/Acme/foo/fooBundle/Listener/ProjectListener.php
>   on line 32**

Comment: It seems like you are testing way too much logic in your test case. You should really be striving to test a single use case on a single method with each test. You also may want to look into mocking out your dependencies (other objects, service calls, etc.).  The end result you have is an extremely fragile test case that, if broken, may take significant debugging to find the root cause.

Comment: Thanks for this advice. I think I need mocking some dependencies too. But I don't find example for my case.

Answer (score 1):

You have some errors in how you are creating your user and logging them in.  I do not know why you are doing so many `static::` calls, but you should only be doing that for creating the client.  For example:

```
private $container;

public function setUp()
{
    $this->client = static::createClient();
    $this->container = $this->client->getContainer();
    $this->em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');

    $this->createAuthorizeClient();
}
```

You do not need to pass `$this->client` to your `createAuthorizeClient()` function.  It should look more like

```
public function createAuthorizeClient()
{
    $session = $this->container->get('session');
    $user = $this->em->getRepository('AcmeFooBundle:User')
        ->findOneByUsername('Nico');

    // rest of the class here
}
```

There might be other issues, but this is just a base set of things you can do.  Take a look at http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/simulating_authentication.html as well for how they create their user for their functional test.

Comment: I Thank you for these tips. I edited my code like you indicated. And I read your link too. **But the problem stays the same**, I fail to get the current user in my "ProjectListenner" when I run the unit test.

Comment: You didn't follow what I stated.  You don't need to explicitly boot the kernel or pass it to your `createAuthorizeClient` function.  Try what I suggested.

Comment: Oh ! you right sorry, bad copy / paste. I edit again.

Comment: Actually, when I replace the programmatically project creation by a creation of the project with the crawler, it's working. The problem still the same, I don't understand how to get the current user in the project Listener when the project creation is from unit test. I'm sorry but I don't understand how to apply your instructions. Have you got an example ?

Comment: Yes the example is already in my answer...try changing your code to match what I put